# sum assigned vlaues if sum for each value meets a specific criterion

Tags: excel, excel-formula

in excel, I have two columns. one containing months of the year (in numbers) each month number occurring in different number of rows, and in the second column I have a duration of time for each row (in hours and minutes). 
now I want to do the following job with an excel function in just one cell (the same job could be done using a table with 12 cells, each for one month but I want to pack it all in one cell): 
1- for each month number, sum all cells in the second column (time) which have that month number in the adjacent cell (this could be done with a sumif ) 
2- if that sum is more than 4 hours then return one for that month else return zero (this step could be done with a formula like this: IF(R10>(--"4:00");1;"") ) 
3. in the end the numbers assigned to each month summed together.

thanks to everyone who helps

the picture below, shows the steps:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8hqf.png)

Comment: =SUM(--(SUMIFS(Table1[time],Table1[month],{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12})>TIME(4,0,0)))

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=SUM(--(SUMIFS(Table1[time],Table1[month],{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12})>TIME(4,0,0)))
```